# $A$ is nowhere dense iff for every nonempty open set $U$, $U\setminus\overline A$ is nonempty

Tags: general-topology

For the first direction I assume that $A$ is nowhere dense, let $U$ be a nonempty set hence $\overline A$ doesn't intersect $U$ so that $U$ intersects the complement of the closure of $A$ so $U$ is a subset of the complement of the closure of $A$ ..
Now I am trying to find the final result but I couldn't .. I don't know if there is something wrong in my proof ??

For the other direction I assume that $U\setminus\overline A$ is nonempty . Then $x$ is in $U$ and $x$ is not in $\overline A$ so $U$ intersects the complement of the closure so $U$ doesn't intersect $\overline A$ and since $U$ is arbitrary it follows that $A$ is nowhere dense..  does the proof for this direction right??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that a subset $A$ is dense in $X$ $\Leftrightarrow$ for every nonempty open set $U$ we have $A∩U \neq\varnothing$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295919/show-that-a-subset-a-is-dense-in-x-leftrightarrow-for-every-nonempty-open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is nowhere dense, let $U$ be a non-empty oepn set. If $U\setminus\overline A=\emptyset$, then $U\subset\overline A$. But then, sense $U\neq\emptyset$, since $U$ is open, and since $\mathring{\overline A}$ is largest open subset of $\overline A$, $\mathring{\overline A}\neq\emptyset$, which is impossible, because $A$ is nowhere dense.

On the other hand, is $A$ is *not* nowhere dense, then $\mathring{\overline A}\neq\emptyset$ is a non-empty open set and $\mathring{\overline A}\setminus\overline A=\emptyset$.

Comment: Does no nowhere dense set means it is dense everywhere?

Comment: No. Nowhere dense means that $\mathring{\overline{A}}=\emptyset$. Therefore, not being nowhere dense means that $\mathring{\overline{A}}\neq\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

I prove it by contradiction. Suppose that $int(cl(A))\neq \emptyset,$ It means that there is $x\in int(cl(A)).$ Consequently, there is open set $U$ which $x\in U$, such that $x\in U \subseteq cl(A)$. Contradiction.

Comment: Yes I got it thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Denoting $X$ the whole space we have to show that                            $A\subseteq X$ nowhere dense $\iff \forall U\subseteq X, U^\circ =U:U\setminus \overline A\neq \varnothing$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Let $U$ an open subset of $X$. If $U\setminus \overline A=\varnothing$, then there is no point of $U$ that does not exist in $\overline A$, which means that every point of $U$ is in $\overline A$, thus $U\subseteq \overline A$, which means that $(\overline A)^\circ\neq\varnothing$  . This is a cotradiction, because $A$ is nowhere dense, so $(\overline A)^\circ=\varnothing$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $A$ is not nowhere dense; then $(\overline A)^\circ\neq\varnothing$, which means that there is an open subset of $X$, let $U$,  which is contained in $\overline A$. Then $U\setminus \overline A=\varnothing$, which contradicts to our main hypothesis. q.e.d.