# $X \setminus A$ is dense iff for every nonempty open set $U$, $U \setminus A$ is nonempty

Tags: general-topology

For the first direction I assume that $X \setminus A$ is dense so that $\mathfrak{cl}(X \setminus A)=X$, let $U$ be a nonempty set if $U \setminus A$ is empty then $U$ is subset from $A$ hence $X \setminus A$ subset from $X \setminus U$ but $X \setminus A$ is subset from $\mathfrak{cl}(X \setminus A)$ so $\mathfrak{cl}(X \setminus A)$ is subset from $X \setminus A$ which contradicts that $X \setminus A$ is dense in $X$ ...
Is this proof correct?
How about the other direction because I worked on it but I can't reach the result ..

Comment: Why are you working with complements? It is equivalent to show that a subset $B \subset X$ is dense if and only if $B \cap U$ is non-empty for all open sets $U$. Also, I suppose you mean $X \setminus U$? As $U \setminus X$ is obviously empty.4

Comment: Yes I edited and I meant X\U

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that a subset $A$ is dense in $X$ $\Leftrightarrow$ for every nonempty open set $U$ we have $A∩U \neq\varnothing$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295919/show-that-a-subset-a-is-dense-in-x-leftrightarrow-for-every-nonempty-open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but it can be made simpler (without using contradiction).

If you set $B=X\setminus A$, then $U\setminus A=U\cap(X\setminus A)=U\cap B$. With this change your statement becomes

> $B$ is dense if and only if, for every nonempty open set $U$, $U\cap B$ is not empty.

Suppose $B$ is dense and that $U$ is a nonempty open set and take $x\in U$. Since $B$ is dense, $x\in\operatorname{cl}(B)$, so for every neighborhood $V$ of $x$, $V\cap B\ne\emptyset$. But $U$ *is* a neighborhood of $x$, so $U\cap B\ne\emptyset$.

Suppose $B$ is not dense. Then there is $x\notin\operatorname{cl}(B)$ and, by definition, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ (so $U$ is open and nonempty) such that $U\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: Much clearer, thank you egreg

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct: If $U$ is open, with $U \setminus A$ empty, then $A$ contains $U$, so $X \setminus U$ contains $X \setminus A$. But $X \setminus U$ is a closed set, so it contains the closure of $X \setminus A$, too. But we assumed $X \setminus A$ was dense, so this closure is all of $X$. Therefore $X \setminus U$ is all of $X$, so $U$ is empty.

Conversely, suppose that for all non-empty open sets $U$, the set $U \setminus A$ is non-empty. Then no non-empty subset of $A$ is open. Taking complements, no *superset* of $X \setminus A$ (except for $X \setminus \emptyset = X$) is closed. Therefore, by definition,
$$Cl(X \setminus A) = \bigcap_{F \supset X \setminus A, \\\text{F closed}}F = X$$
as required.

Comment: So for the converse part, do you mean cl(X\A) ?

Comment: Yes! In fact I meant $X \setminus A$ in several places. It should be fixed, now.

Comment: Ok yes so you proved it with respect to A.. Thank you very much it is really helpful