# Show that $A$ is dense in $X$ if and only if every nonempty open set of $X$ contains a point of $A$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Show that $A$ is dense in $X$ if and only if every nonempty open set of $X$ contains a point of $A$.

I did not think there was much to prove for this, if using the theorem:$x \in \bar A$ if for each open set $U$ containing $x$, $U \cap A \neq \varnothing$.

Attempt:

$(\Rightarrow)$
If A is dense, then $\bar A=X$. So for each $x \in X$, there is an open set $U$ containing $x$ with $U \cap A \neq \varnothing$. Since $x$ was arbitrary this holds for each $x \in X$, so each open set in $X$ contains points in $A$.

$(\Leftarrow)$If each open set contains points in $A$, for any $x \in X$ and open set $U$ containing $x$, $U \cap A \neq \varnothing$. So $\bar A=X$.

I do not know if this proof is actually okay. I have seen a different proof in "topology without tears", that is much more involved, using a proof by contradiction in one direction. Am I over simplifying this, and is my proof unsuccessful? Any help will or criticism be appreciated.

Comment: It really is that simple.

Comment: What you are missing: In the first direction you haven't considered every open set.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott (and the two upvoters) No, it's not. Not quite.

Comment: @amsmath I was thinking I considered every open set because the union of open sets is equal to $X$.So if it is true for every open set about every point, it must be true for all open sets.

Comment: In your first implication, you write "there is an open set $U$". That's an existential statement (even about sets about the point $x$, contrary to your latest comment), not the required universal statement. Fortunately you can rescue it from the theorem you quote—you've used a much weaker result.

Comment: @amsmath: Yes, every non-empty open set **has** been considered in the first direction, though it should have been stated more clearly: if $U\ne\varnothing$ is open, there is an $x\in U$, and $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$, so $U\cap A\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Nope. Logically, it was just insufficient.

Comment: "Every nonempty open set of $X$ contains a point of $A$" is THE DEFINITION of "$A$ is dense in $X$". Apparently you are using some alternative definition. In that case, you need to TELL US WHAT DEFINITION YOU ARE USING. if you want us to help you.

Comment: @bof: The definition being used is clear from the arguments offered: $A$ is dense in $X$ if $\operatorname{cl}A=X$. While I much prefer the one that you give, the other is very common.

Comment: @amsmath: As I said in my second comment, the statement is inadequate, and had I had time when I first commented, I’d have gone into detail on that point, as I usually do in such cases. It is, however, clear to me that the OP understood what is going on. And as I said, it really is that simple, even when stated properly. (By the way, had I been giving unqualified approval, I’d have said that the argument was fine, or words to that effect, though I do not expect you to know that.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that a subset $A$ is dense in $X$ $\Leftrightarrow$ for every nonempty open set $U$ we have $A∩U \neq\varnothing$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295919/show-that-a-subset-a-is-dense-in-x-leftrightarrow-for-every-nonempty-open)

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed that simple: if $\overline{A} = X$ and $U$ is non-empty open, then we can argue as you did: let $x \in U$ then $x \in \overline{A}$ , so any open neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$ (in particular $U$ too) so $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

Conversely, if $A$ intersects every non-empty open set, then $\overline{A}=X$ or else $U = X\setminus \overline{A}$ would be a non-empty open set disjoint from $A$, or: let $x \in X$, $U$ any open neighbourhood of $x$, by assumption $A$ intersects $U$ so by the criterion you mentioned $x \in \overline{A}$, so $X \subseteq \overline{A}$ and so $X=\overline{A}$.